# SQL Azure Reporting

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, azure-sql-database

For everyone playing with SQL Azure, what are you using for reporting? Do the Visual Studio reports connect seamlessly? What about reporting services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reporting Services will still connect and work as normal, BUT there is no SSRS service on the Azure platform.  So it means that you will connect (most likely through ADO) from a different data centre (either your own or hosted SSRS) to SQL Azure, meaning that potentially a lot (too much) data has to come down the wire.

SSRS and SSAS for Azure are not officially on the Azure roadmap yet

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation for a very fast, full featured reporting solution is [Izenda Reports](http://www.izenda.com). It runs on SQL Azure and is designed for OEM integration with other Azure apps.  It streams data from an Azure db or from an off-site db.  Just give it a connection string and go.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Azure Reporting was just announced at PDC10 (Oct 28, 2010) and a CTP should be available by the end of the year:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140407031450/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/10/28/10081543.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

We have at least one customer using [ActiveReports](http://www.datadynamics.com/ActiveReports) with SQL Azure. Just connect with the normal SQL provider for ADO.NET or you can use [unbound mode](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/arWLKGroupOnUnboundFields.html) with ActiveReports.